# Leave US with ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, esta, peru

I'm from Germany and I have an approved ESTA. I already bought flights to the US and back and I'm staying for 6 weeks. But now I'm thinking about spending around two weeks in Peru. Would it be possible to leave the US to Peru and return to the US after a few weeks with my ESTA?

Comment: In a word, *yes.*

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem. Is there something in particular that you are concerned about?

Comment: We have to point out that ESTA is not what governs your admission to the US. ESTA is just permission to get on a plane. The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) governs the conditions of your admission.